# Kestrel it's not starting when I use an Extension method on the IApplicationBuilder interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have the following code in an empty ASP.NET Core project:

`Program.cs`:

```
using Esercizio_6.CustomMiddleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddTransient<LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware>();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseLoginAuthenticatorMiddleware();

app.Run(async context =>{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(" Hi this is the Run method \n");
});
```

I have created a folder `CustomMiddleware` in the solution and inside I have added the class

`LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware.cs`:

```
namespace Esercizio_6.CustomMiddleware
{
    public class LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Calling LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware\n");
            await next(context);
        }
    }

    public static class LoginAuthenticatorMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseLoginAuthenticatorMiddleware( this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            return app.UseMiddleware<LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add an extension method to the IApplicationBuilder interface, I've seen that you can do this in 2 ways:
- you can create a class and the implement the IMiddleware interface and then add the static class for the Extensions method

```
   - you can create directly the Middleware class
```

I'm trying with the first one, so creating a class and implementing the IMiddleware interface.

When I try to start this project, for some reason kestrel don't want to start, I don't understand why, could you help me? thanks :)

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm sorry, right, not the kernel XD , the kestrel! sorry about that :)

Comment: Do you have a [mre] you can post somewhere? Try manually deleting bin and obj folders JIC and restarting VS.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron I have modified the code above as a minimal reproducible example, if you try it, the kestrel should explode for some reason, the message should be like "web server failed to listen on port 'your port'. If you comment all the part of the LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware in the Program.cs and rebuild, even if you delete the bin or obj folders and restar vs, the kestrel should still explode for some reason XD, it's beautifull when a simple test give you reasons to cry ahahaha

Comment: (1) The error message in the image is DIFFERENT from what you show in the Question Title. Never do that, always make it accurate! (2) The error is happening **inside a Visual Studio Watch**, during a debugging session. Your are trying to inspect the class `LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware` but **classes can not be inspected** and that is precisely what the Watch window is trying to tell you. So there is NO ERROR in your code, there is just an invalid "value" in the Watch window that can't be inspected.

Comment: @PeterB the thing is, that not even I can understand what is happening, it's for that reason that I'm asking for help, If I could understand the error then it will be easier to find a solution, but HERE it's a little bit confusing, I'm still "learning" . As you've said there's NO ERROR in my code, BUT, for some reason, the kestrel don't want to start. the next time I will make my title more clear, it was my FIRST question in this forum. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.Run(...)` does not do what you think. It is actually a [`RunExtensions.Run(IApplicationBuilder, RequestDelegate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which:

> Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline.

If you check the implementation it actually just calls `app.Use` internally.

so you need to add `app.Run()` at the end:

```cs
app.Run(async context =>{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync(" Hi this is the Run method \n");
});

app.Run();
```

A lot more info about what it is can be found in the [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article.

As for the screenshot - you can watch a class name in debugger (as you can't write something like `var x = LoginAuthenticatorMiddleware;`)

Comment: *facepalm* yes, it works! I misinterpreted the Run method, I thought it finished the middleware pipeline and therefore nothing else was needed at the end, lol, Thank you! @Guru!